# Unexpected HTML Error Response using Python Sockets

Tags: python, html, apache, sockets, http-status-code-404

I am following a tutorial to retrieve the HTML from a webpage using Python Sockets found [here](http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-the-recv-socket-function-in-python/).

I have an Apache server running on an Ubuntu guest that is hosting a single HTML file for my website.  I have made a DNS entry on my host OS's `/etc/hosts` file to make the webpage accessible with the url `vulnerable`.

I have verified that my webpage can be accessed from a web browser on my host machine.

I have made a few modifications to the code to fit my case.

```
import socket
import sys  # needed for sys.exit()

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print ("Failed to initialize socket")
    sys.exit()

print ("Socket initialized")

host = "vulnerable"
port = 80

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror as e:
    print ("Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting")
    sys.exit()

s.connect((remote_ip, port))

print ("Socket Connected to " +host+ " on IP " + remote_ip)

message = "GET /HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".encode('utf-8')   # convert string to byte message, otherwise won't send

try:
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    print ("Send Failed")
    sys.exit()

print ("Message sent successfully")

reply = s.recv(4096)
print (reply)
```

When I try to retrieve the HTML from my website, I get an unexpected Error 404.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /HTTP/1.1 was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I do not understand why I am getting this 404 error when I can reach my webpage from a web browser without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem

`message = "GET /HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".encode('utf-8')`

You need to specify the resource you want to retrieve -- that's why you're receiving `The requested URL /HTTP/1.1 was not found on this server` as a response from the web server. You're requesting the resource `/HTTP/1.1`, which is not found and results in the 404 response.

In `message` make sure you specify the resource you want to retrieve, like

`message = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".encode('utf-8')`

Comment: This was it! Thank you!